# Get solution folder name in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am struggling to get solution folder names in the TFS drop locations.

I have a .NET solution file in the following hirerchy:

Solution File

--> Solution Folder A --> Project A

--> Solution Folder B --> Project B & Project C

Now I want my drop location should be customized like the above project hierarchy.

means : in the Drop Location it should be : SolutionName -> SolutionFolderName -> ProjectName -> {build output}

By implementing customize output directory in my build template , i.e. $(TeamBuildOutDir)\$(SolutionName)\$(MSBuildProjectName), I am getting Solution Name -> Project Name -> Build outputs..

But I am not getting Solution Folder names to structure my outputs. Can anybody suggest how to get this so that I can read from my project files. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution folders don't exist in the file system.

Comment: Hi Demon Bee, welcome to stackoverflow. I noticed your Answer posted below, just some help to make things flow smoother, reply to others answers by using 'add comment' on their answer. You only need to add an answer to your own question, if you think you have solved it yourself and want to share your solution. Have fun!

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a property in the projects that corresponds to the solution folder name (e.g. `$(SolutionFolder)`). Then you could set the output directory to `$(TeamBuildOutDir)\$(SolutionFolder)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static TeamProject[] GetAllProjects(TfsTeamProjectCollection prjCollection)
    {   
        var versionControl = prjCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        return versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(true);
    }
    public static ProjectCollection GetAllIterations(TfsTeamProjectCollection prjCollection)
    {
         var wiStore = prjCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
         return wiStore.Projects;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// function to get all system project name
    /// </summary>
    private void IterateFolder()
    {
        try
        {  var selectedProject = "EMRConversion";

            Project detailsOfTheSelectedProject = null;

            var projCollections = GetAllIterations(prjCollection);

            foreach (Project project in projCollections)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedProject))
                {
                    if (project.Name.ToString().Contains(selectedProject))
                    {
                        detailsOfTheSelectedProject = project;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (detailsOfTheSelectedProject != null)
            {
                cmbSystemName.Items.Clear();

                foreach (Node area in detailsOfTheSelectedProject.AreaRootNodes)
                {
                    if (!(area.HasChildNodes))
                    {
                        cmbSystemName.Items.Add(area.Name);
                    }

                    foreach (Node item in area.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        cmbSystemName.Items.Add(item.Name);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```